# DOCTYPE breaks nth-child background colors

Tags: php, html, css, doctype

My CSS is validated, but still breaks when adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`.  What am I doing wrong?  I have search the forums and the common response seems to be [add height: 100% to the body, html tags.  Did that, but no luck.

Without DOCTYPE: http://www.babeweiser.com/rockhistory/
With DOCTYPE: http://www.babeweiser.com/rockhistory/test.php

**CSS**

```
html, body 
{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: #333333; 
}
div.Container
{
margin: auto;
width: 90%;
background: #5e6d3d;
padding: 10px;
}
p 
{
font-family: sans-serif;
}
.Table
{
    display: Table;
}
.Title
{
    display: table-caption;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    background: #c6d4a8;
}
.Heading
{
    display: table-row;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.Row
{
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
div.row:nth-child(odd)
{
background: #daedb2;
}
div.row:nth-child(even)
{
background: #c6d4a8;
}
.Cell
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 15px;
}
select:required:invalid 
{
color: #999;
}
option {
color: #000;
}
```

**test.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Today in Rock History</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rockhistory2.css">

<script>
$(function() {
  $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "pull_history2.php",  
      data: "" + status,  
      success: function(data){  
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;

      }  
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $(document).on('submit', '#reg-form', function()
    {

        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'pull_history2.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data)
                {       
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>



</head>

<body>

<div class="Container">
<form id="reg-form" name="reg-form" method="post">
<select name="month" required  id="month" size="1">
<option value="" disabled selected>Month</option>
<?php 
$mo = 1; 
while($mo <= 12) {
    echo '<option value= "' . $mo . '">' . date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mo+1, 0, 0)) . '</option>';
    echo "\n";
    $mo++;
} 
?>
</select>
<select name="day" required id="day" size="1">
<option value="" disabled selected>Day</option>
<?php
$da = 1; 
while($da <= 31) {
    echo '<option value= "' . $da . '">' . date("j", mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, $da, 0)) . '</option>';
    echo "\n";
    $da++;
} 
?>

 </select>
 <button type="submit" >Go</button>

 </form>

    <p id="demo"></p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**pull_history2.php:**

```
<?php

if($_POST) {
    $month= $_POST['month'];
    $day= $_POST['day'];
} else {
    $month = date('n');
    $day = date('j');
}

$tdate=date("F j", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, 0));

?>
<div class="Table">
    <div class="Title">
        <p><? echo "This Day in Rock History for $tdate" ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class-"heading"> 
    </div>

<?php
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx", "xxx");
    mysql_select_db("babewe5_wlup",$db);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM RockHistory081512 WHERE      month=$month AND day=$day ORDER BY year",$db);
        if (!$result) { echo("ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "\n$SQL\n"); }
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
            ?>

            <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell">
                            <p><? echo $row["year"] ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell">
                            <p><? echo $row["history"] ?></p>                       
                    </div>
            </div>
            <?
            }
            mysql_free_result ($result);
            ?>

<div class="Row">
     <div class="Cell">
     </div>
     <div class="Cell">
           <p><small>Copyright &copy; <? echo date("Y"); ?> Tim Spencer</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: variables, class names etc. are all case-sensitive. see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.Row` and `.row` in your CSS. One is initial caps and the other is not. Change `div.row:nth-child` to `div.Row:nth-child`.

Applying the `doctype` enforces a set of rules on your document. Without the `doctype` the two are treated the same.

Comment: same thing for `div.row:nth-child(even)` edit: Ok, I think you meant for both. Nice catch.

Comment: One thing though. bootstrap uses similar class naming conventions and they should be careful with that. It just leaves room of a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It is the case sensitivity. either modify classname to "row" (lowercase letters). or change the relevant styles in stylesheet.

div.Row:nth-child(even)  -> (R as uppercase).. 
div.Row:nth-child(odd)

You better check the browser compatibilities of n-th selectors.. It is supported in IE 9 and higher versions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: oh please, an answer's already been given. This is just a piggyback answer. Plus, their answer "explains" it in detail.

Comment: I noticed the other answer  after i posted the answer. I was investigating his links. after finding the problem, i switched the tab without reloading the page and clicked "Answer" button. You can downvote my answer if you please. But it is not wrong..

Comment: fair enough. Well, the OP has enough information to get their code going then.